# ¿Por qué hay perdida de milisegundos al migrar los datos de SQL SERVER a Postgresql Usando delphi XE7?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, postgresql, delphi, migration

Cuando migro los datos de SQL SERVER (datetime2(4)) a PostgreSQL (Timestamp(4) With Time Zone) hay perdida de milisegundos como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo:

### SQL Server: DateTime2(4)

### 2017-03-30 15:10:15.1234

### PostgreSQL: Timestamp(4) With Time Zone

### 2017-03-30 15:10:15.123

Estoy usando el componente de firedac TFDDataMove para migrar los datos, asi es como lo configuro

```
FDTable1.Active:= False;
FDDataMove1.CommitCount:=100;
FDDataMove1.StatictsInterval:=100;
FDDataMove1.TextDataDef.StrEmpty2Null:=False;
FDDataMove1.Mode:=dmAlwaysInsert;
FDDataMove1.Options:= [poOptimiseDest,poOptimiseSrc,poClearDest,poAbortOnExc,poIdentityInsert];
FDDataMove1.Source:=FDQuery2;
FDDataMove1.Destination:=FDTable2;


Version SQL SERVER: 2014
Version PostgreSQL: 9.6.3 
Version Firedac: 11.0.1(Build 73709)
Version Rad Studio: RAD Studio XE7


    =================================================
    Client info:
    =================================================
    Loading Driver PG...
    Client brand = PostgreSQL regular
    Client version = 906040000
    Client DLL name: C\...\Proyect_Migration\bin\libpg.dll

    =================================================
    Session info
    =================================================
    Current catalog =
    Current schema = public
    Server version = 9.6.3
    Server Encoding = UTF8
    Client Encoding = UTF8
    Is Superuser = on
    Session Authorization = postgres
    date Style = ISO,DMY
    Integer date/time = on
    Time zone = America/Mexico_City
    Standard conforming string = on
```

Comment: Solo, para ser formales, los milisegundos van de 0 a 999 (por eso se llaman **mili** segundos). Lo que estás perdiendo son fracciones de milisegundo, de hecho, las décimas de milisegundo que ya son micro-segundos...